# How to call from a C# applicaiton a C++ function taking a pointer to void?

Tags: c#, char, dllimport

I have a dynamic library (`.dll`) written in C++ exporting a function I'd like to use in my C# applicaiton:

```cpp
int SendText(void* pControl, char* sText);
```

How can I, given it takes a pointer to void?

Comment: `sText` will marshal as a string, but what does `pControl` represent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for `void*` you can just use `IntPtr` ,
strings will work with the `MarshalAs` attribute:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int SendText(IntPtr pControl, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string sText);
```